# Extension won't load my local HTML file

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I currently have the [switcheroo redirector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/switcheroo-redirector/cnmciclhnghalnpfhhleggldniplelbg) chrome extension installed and it's used to redirects a URL to a different URL.

> For example: facebook.com > google.com

I would like to redirect a web URL to a local file which does not work when the link of the local file is added to the extension.

> For example: facebook.com > facebook.html (local file on my PC)

Answer (score 0):

It seems running a local server would be a good idea for such case. So the redirect would look like this:

```
facebook.com > localhost:8000/facebook.html
```

Comment: And how do I make a "local server" and put any website I want in it?